# Apache Rewrite htaccess in subdir

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

let me get to the point.

I have a php project that has this structure

```
ROOT
.htaccess
--api/
----public/
------index.php
------test.html
--backoffice/
```

And what I want is to use the index.php of api/public to get it working like

```
domain.com/api/index.php
```

instead of

```
domain.com/api/public/index.php
```

I've been trying with no success the rewritebase or rewriterules of .htaccess, I'm missing something? putting the .htaccess in the wrong directory? I have to use multiple .htaccess?

**UPDATED**:  So I got my two .htaccess files, by now I'm able to access with the url domain.com/api/index.php but it throws 401 , it's something... on the other hand I can access to the file test.html located under /api/public with the current url domain.com/api/test.html

Here are the .htaccess
**domain.com/api/ .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/public/$1
```

**domain.com/api/public/ .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a seperate `.htaccess` file `in your API folder` with a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /public [R=301,L]
```

So this should redirect internally to the subfolder `public`

```
ROOT
  | --api/
  |     |-- .htaccess 
  |     |-- public/
  |             |-- index.php
  |-- backoffice/
```

**Update1**

I think in your case this should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/public/$1 [L]
```

It depends also on the System which you are using and the preset.

**Update2**

I did some test on XAMPP an got to following result

Put your `.htaccess` in the `ROOT folder`, 
`delete` all other `.htaccess files in subfolders`. 
Rename `api` to `_api` or something, as you like

```
ROOT
  | --.htaccess
  | --/_api/  <<<------- rename
  |     |-- /public/
  |             |-- index.php
  |-- /backoffice/
```

add this `.htaccess` to root

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteRule ^api2/(.*)$ /api/public/$1 [B,L,QSA]
```

Call as before `yoursite.com/api`

This scenario worked on my test system as expected. Give it a try.

Comment: That rule will redirect my url to domain.com/public I edited my question if you can take a look

Comment: Can you give some infos on the enviroment you are testing? When you call a folder without a index file, is it redirected automatically, without a htaccess file?

Comment: @lfelisiak give Update2 a try.

Comment: When calling a folder without index, the error is Forbidden (Because of the option Index disabled) I tried the Update2, and I'm getting a 404 not found.

Comment: Could be some config by the hosting provider? should I get in touch with them and ask?

Comment: @lfelisiak When you call a folder without an index.* then sure you will get an error. If no file is specified like yoursite.com/api/ then automatically it is looking up for an index file. This behavior is predefined, normally, on your host. So do yoursite.com/api/otherpage.php. Let me know if your initial question is solved.

Comment: But if we are redirecting to /api/public shouldn't it reach to /api/public/index.php by default?

Comment: @lfelisiak only if it is set in your apache config. You can put DirectoryIndex index.php index.html on top of it after rewrite engine on